# align="right" disables button

Tags: html, css

I want a button at the right corner of a div. It works fine normally, but upon adding the align="right" to the html, the button doesn't work anymore (although it does align to the right).

```
<input id="exitbutton" align="right" style="width:15px" type="image" src="images/#"/>
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: My advice: 1) Use CSS instead of the `align` attribute 2) Don't use inline CSS.

Comment: align is an obsolete attribute, use float . Your code cannot show your issue. Please set up a snippet or post html/css that reproduce your trouble . this is what you give us https://jsfiddle.net/3bdcuz5x/ and it works

Comment: it seems `align` attribut doesn't exist for type="image"
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/image

Comment: use float:right css in external style sheet.try to avoid inline css

Comment: @makonnendossantos even then, just like this it works in FF https://jsfiddle.net/3bdcuz5x/ problem must be else where :) hard to guess what sort of html and css is around

Answer (score 2):

Ideally `align="right"` is not the property of input tag if you are using HTML5. As you are already applying inline style, you can just apply `float:right` to align input button to the right.

```
<input id="exitbutton" style="width:15px; float:right" type="image" src="images/#"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

For buttons instead of using inline attributes use text alignment in your css. And avoid giving style with attributes as much as you can.

For form elements you should use float if you are not using flex. But keep it in mind you should clear floats in order to prevent visual errors

Answer (score 0):

`align` property is not  for an input field
You can use `float`  like this:

```css
input{float:right;}
```

```html
<input id="exitbutton" style="width:15px" type="image" src="images/#"/>
```